# UI-Router: get a reference to the scope that is going to dissapear in updateView?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

All the events related with UI-Router ($stateChangeStart, $stateChangeSuccess, $viewContentLoading...) seems to be broadcasted from $rootScope but one, $viewContentLoaded that is emitted from the scope of the ui-view that is going to replace the current one. My question is, is there some way to get a reference to the scope that is going to be replaced?

I'm missing something like:

```
 if (!firstTime && previousLocals === latestLocals) return; // nothing to do
 newScope = scope.$new();
 latestLocals = $state.$current.locals[name];

 if (!firstTime)
    currentScope.$broadcast('$viewToBeReplaced');
```

Also I could listen in my views scope to $stateChangeSuccess, but I don't know how to check if that scope is affected by the state change. And $scope.destroy() is other option, but that function is called after the ui-view has been replaced for the new one.

Comment: can I ask what your use case for this is?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to apply a class to elements within a view with two conditions: 
a) the view is going to dissapear
b) the element is in the viewport
By now, the best solution that I found is setting a variable in the scope and use something like ng-class="{ 'dissapear': viewLeaving & iAmInViewport}" . This variable is set by a service or directive listening to the rootScope event $viewContentLoading. 

At the end my animation looks like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWnyFwqJ5i8 . Maybe there are easy ways to do it.

Comment: I must admit I don't know much about animation, but UI-Router adds a class to an ui-view when it's being removed from the DOM.  See the source code https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/viewDirective.js#L150 and see https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/docs/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate#leave for what $animate.leave() does